# Retrieving auth token for facebook account configured in mobile via account manager in android

Tags: android, facebook, oauth-2.0, accountmanager

I am trying to get Auth token for a facebook account configured in device via account manager in android using

```
accountManager.getAuthToken(account,"user_activities",null,Hellol10n.this, new   GetAuthTokenCallback(), null);// account is of type "com.facebook.auth.login"
```

But i dont get any result. The callback is not getting invoked at all.

Does facebook support this way of getting auth token. Facebook do use oauth2. So have a look at

> This lesson demonstrates connecting to a Google server that supports OAuth2. Although Google services are used as an example, the techniques demonstrated will work on any service that correctly supports the OAuth2 protocol."

http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html

Also, i am trying this becoz i dont want the user to type in the credentials for an account he has already configured in the device to make the user experience simple.

UPDATE:

Also account manager has a fb account of type "com.sec.android.app.snsaccountfacebook.account_type" even if the facebook app is not installed. Is it not possible to get the auth of this account.What is the difference between the account types "com.sec.android.app.snsaccountfacebook.account_type" and "com.facebook.auth.login" in account manager

Comment: Unless this is documented in the Facebook reference, it is most likely not supported. Where did you get the "user_activities" string from?

Comment: I got it from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/user-friend-permissions/

Comment: That page doesn't mention neither tokenType, nor `AccountManager`.

Comment: I thought this permission could be used for token type like the scope for google. I just tried on my own. I dont know if this is right. But do u think there is a flaw

Comment: What you found is totally unrelated. What you are trying to do might be possible, but you need to know the right token type. Ask on Facebook SDK support  or related forums. However, it is totally possible that this is not supported, so you'll have to use their SDK.

Comment: Ok. Can you give me the link where i can ask this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the [Facebook SDK for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/android/) instead. If the user has the Facebook app, then SSO simply switches to the app for authentication and authorization, and there's no need to reenter the username/password. If the user does not have the Facebook app, then the accountManager.getAuthToken mechanism wouldn't work anyways since Android wouldn't have the account info.

Comment: Thanx Ming Li. I understand and have tried. Its working fine. But i am trying to have a same account manager code that would fetch auth token irrespective of service providers(google,facebook). I am breaking my head over this. Can you tell me if this is possible through account manager.

Comment: Using the SDK served the same way i was expecting. Thanx Ming Li