# Can I use the sync adapter in android with a facebook account?

Tags: android, facebook, accountmanager, android-syncadapter

I know I can use the  facebook SDK to allow a User to log into my app. I have also read that it is best to use the SDK instead of the accountmanager because of the token expiration and also the facebook app my not be installed on the device. I want to be able to use the sync adapter to sync data from the device to a server.

As I am authenticating the User via the SDK and not using accounmanager, can I still use the sync adapter with the account used by the User to log in?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but the sync adapter requires an account, so you would have to follow the instructions in the sync adapter docs to create a dummy account in the account manager just for your sync adapter. http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html#CreateAccountTypeAccount

Your sync adapter would basically ignore this dummy account argument to performSync. The account used by the user to log in is not really relevant to your sync adapter. What you're interested in is the user's facebook account. You need to store some information somewhere like in SharedPreferences that your sync adapter can use to know what user and any other details it needs when it is authorizing with the facebook sdk.

Your app would need an activity to have the user initially sign in with facebook so you can save the details in the shared preferences. Then it can enable the sync adapter.

Comment: I was thinking about checking if the user already was signed in with Facebook, then couldn't I just retrieve stored credentials from other apps with syncadapter?

Comment: If the facebook sdk offers that kind of single signon, you could do that. Personally, I would off the user the ability to change the facebook account used by the app in the settings.

Comment: it is more about checking for available credentials to determine something unique about the current user and offering to use those, instead of confronting the user with signin/sign-out pains - which they can optional do in settings if they want. So the app would check if the user has a "facebook" account already in their android system, which is generated by having the facebook app installed at all. Do you know if SyncAdapter helps with what I imagine

Comment: All of the advice I can find suggests the facebook account in the account manager will not help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972760/retrieving-auth-token-for-facebook-account-configured-in-mobile-via-account-mana